# Powershell: New-LocalUser -A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'True'

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

I have been following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/new-localuser?view=powershell-5.1) to try and write a powershell script to add a new local user to windows.

I need a username, fullname, description and password, and to check `PasswordNeverExpires` and `UserMayNotChangePassword`. I have written the following in an attempt to do so:

```
$Password = Read-Host -AsSecureString -Prompt 'Create password for new user account:'
New-LocalUser -Name "NewUser" -FullName "New User" -Description "New Execution Account" -Password $Password -PasswordNeverExpires $true -UserMayNotChangePassword $true
```

However, when running this I get the following error:

> New-LocalUser : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
>   argument 'True'. At line:2 char:1
>   + New-LocalUser -Name "NewUser" -FullName "New User" -Description "New ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-LocalUser], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewLocalUserCommand

If anyone can see where I've gone wrong I would greatly appreciate any help or advice, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last two parameters are switch parameters. You don't need to pass arguments to them. It's enough to simply provide them as they are. Like this:

```
$Password = Read-Host -AsSecureString -Prompt 'Create password for new user account:'
New-LocalUser -Name "NewUser" -FullName "New User" -Description "New Execution Account" -Password $Password -PasswordNeverExpires -UserMayNotChangePassword
```

Comment: If you want to pass values to them anyway you'd do it like this: `-UserMayNotChangePassword:$true`.